# Instantiate a class in another class's constructor

Tags: php

I'd like to instantiate a class once, within another class' constructor, and then have access to it from all the functions of the class.

If you look at the following class, you can see that in function foo, I instantiate CLibrary and then call a function (callFn). This works fine.

What I would like to do is to instantiate CLibrary in the constructor (see comment) and then be able to use that variable ($library) in foo to access callFn (see the comments).

But this does not seem to work.

Can anybody help?

```
class CTweeting {
  private $library;
  private $ROOT;
  private $PHP_CLASSES;

  function __construct) {
        $this->ROOT        = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $this->PHP_CLASSES = $this->ROOT . "/php/classes/";
    require_once($this->PHP_CLASSES . 'CLibrary.php'); 
    //$library = new CLibrary(); // ** I would like to uncomment this line **



  public function foo() {
    $library = new CLibrary(); // …. delete this line
        $library->callFn();  // … and change this line to ‘$this->library->callFn();’
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `$this->library = new CLibrary();` and `$this->library->callFn();`

Comment: You can assign as `$this->library = new CLibrary();` in constructor.

Comment: Ahhh - I'll try that. New to PHP and ALWAYS forget the $this. Many thanks. G

Comment: @Graham this is not specific to PHP only. It is a basic concept of OOP that whenever you want to reference a property or method of a class within it, you use "this". In this scenario, you are trying to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

The $library variable can be used in your class constructor by doing `$this->library`

So the code should look like this:

class CTweeting {
  private $library;
  private $ROOT;
  private $PHP_CLASSES;

```
     function __construct) {
            $this->ROOT        = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $this->PHP_CLASSES = $this->ROOT . "/php/classes/";
        require_once($this->PHP_CLASSES . 'CLibrary.php'); 
        $this->library = new CLibrary(); 

........
.......
........
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaned up version, using `$this->library` in the constructor and the `foo() method`

```
class CTweeting {
  private $library;
  private $ROOT;
  private $PHP_CLASSES;

  function __construct() {
     $this->ROOT        = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
     $this->PHP_CLASSES = $this->ROOT . "/php/classes/";
     require_once($this->PHP_CLASSES . 'CLibrary.php'); 
     $this->library = new CLibrary();
  }

  public function foo() {
     $this->library->callFn();
  }
}
```